# Add featured blog area to Shopify article template

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I'm using shopify which allows a dynamic section on the home page to show 3 blog posts however this only appears on the homepage.

I would like to add the featured blog section that’s used on my Shopify home page, in the bottom of the Blog article template

I have added the {% section ‘featured-blog’ %} to the article.liquid template below {% section ‘article-template’ %} and it displays the 3 blog items but with dummy text and images, it can’t seem to get my actual blog posts? I must be missing something to get the actual blog content but I cant seem to figure it out!

Any ideas or help would be very very appreciated!

[image]

Output gets dummy text instead of my blog posts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All is good in your world! You need to navigate to an Article that is assigned to that template within your theme settings panel. Configuration settings for the Index (home page) and that Article template are distinct. It is awaiting your input and currently showing the default fallbacks.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the heads up but I want the featured blogs to display on the blog post article pages - I'm not sure how I get this to output? There are no settings for this on any other areas, only if I add the blog area to the home page blocks do I get customise settings for this area.

Comment: You need to navigate to the blog post article page _within the theme editor_ and the settings will then be there, just as when you are viewing the home page the settings for that are there